# how to pass mxgraph generated xml to Action of controller?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, mxgraph

I have started a project using asp.net mvc5 and then downloaded the mxGraph project from its original source of github https://github.com/jgraph/mxgraph

I have loaded mxgraph www folder and also src folder in my mvc project and edited my Index.cshtml file as below

```
    <!--[if IE]><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=5,IE=9" ><! 
    [endif]-->
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Grapheditor</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles/grapheditor.css">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var urlParams = (function(url)
            {
                var result = new Object();
                var idx = url.lastIndexOf('?');
                if (idx > 0)
                {
                    var params = url.substring(idx + 1).split('&');
                    for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i++)
                    {
                        idx = params[i].indexOf('=');
                        if (idx > 0)
                        {
                            result[params[i].substring(0, idx)] = params[i].substring(idx + 1);
                        }
                    }
                }
                return result;
            })(window.location.href);
            mxLoadResources = false;
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/Init.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/deflate/pako.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/deflate/base64.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/jscolor/jscolor.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/sanitizer/sanitizer.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/src/js/mxClient.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/EditorUi.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/Editor.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/Sidebar.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/Graph.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/Format.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/Shapes.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/Actions.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/Menus.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/Toolbar.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/Dialogs.js"></script>
    </head>
        <body class="geEditor">
            <script type="text/javascript">

            (function() {
                var editorUiInit = EditorUi.prototype.init;
                EditorUi.prototype.init = function() {
                    editorUiInit.apply(this, arguments);
                    this.actions.get('export').setEnabled(false);
                    if (!Editor.useLocalStorage)
                    {
                        mxUtils.post(OPEN_URL, '', mxUtils.bind(this, function(req) {
                            var enabled = req.getStatus() != 404;
                            this.actions.get('open').setEnabled(enabled || Graph.fileSupport);
                            this.actions.get('import').setEnabled(enabled || Graph.fileSupport);
                            this.actions.get('save').setEnabled(enabled);
                            this.actions.get('saveAs').setEnabled(enabled);
                            this.actions.get('export').setEnabled(enabled);
                        }));
                    }
                };
                mxResources.loadDefaultBundle = false;
                var bundle = mxResources.getDefaultBundle(RESOURCE_BASE, mxLanguage) || mxResources.getSpecialBundle(RESOURCE_BASE, mxLanguage);

                mxUtils.getAll([bundle, /*STYLE_PATH +*/ '/styles/default.xml'], function(xhr) {
                    mxResources.parse(xhr[0].getText());
                    var themes = new Object();
                    themes[Graph.prototype.defaultThemeName] = xhr[1].getDocumentElement();

                    new EditorUi(new Editor(urlParams['chrome'] == '0', themes));
                }, function() {
                    document.body.innerHTML = '<center style="margin-top:10%;">Error loading resource files. Please check browser console.</center>';
                });
            })();
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

this page loads properly.
and my init.js is as below:

```
// URLs for save and export
    window.EXPORT_URL = window.EXPORT_URL || '/export';
    window.SAVE_URL = window.SAVE_URL || 'save';
    window.OPEN_URL = window.OPEN_URL || '/open.html';
    window.RESOURCES_PATH = window.RESOURCES_PATH || '/resources';
    window.RESOURCE_BASE = window.RESOURCE_BASE || window.RESOURCES_PATH + '/grapheditor';
    window.STENCIL_PATH = window.STENCIL_PATH || '/stencils';
    window.IMAGE_PATH = window.IMAGE_PATH || '/images';
    window.STYLE_PATH = window.STYLE_PATH || '/styles';
    window.CSS_PATH = window.CSS_PATH || '/styles';
    window.OPEN_FORM = window.OPEN_FORM || '/open.html';
    window.mxBasePath = window.mxBasePath || '/src';
    window.mxLanguage = window.mxLanguage || urlParams['lang'];
    window.mxLanguages = window.mxLanguages || ['de'];
```

and now i want to pass the generated xml to my Action after drawing diagram and click on File/Save.

Comment: Xml is a string and you can simply same the string xml using File methods in c# like StreamWriter or File.WriteAllText(filename).  You do not need to parse the xml in your code before saving unless you need to process the xml or save only part of the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for Reply. I found solution of my mean.

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<!--[if IE]><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=5,IE=9" ><![endif]-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!--head is as past and jquery added-->
    //previous repeated code collapsed for brevity 

    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body class="geEditor">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Extends EditorUi to update I/O action states based on availability of backend
        (function () {
            var editorUiInit = EditorUi.prototype.init;

            EditorUi.prototype.init = function () {
                editorUiInit.apply(this, arguments);
                this.actions.get('export').setEnabled(false);

                //previous repeated code collapsed for brevity 

                this.editor.setFilename('doc1.xml');

                //save editorUi object
                var editorUI = this;

                //this part shal be inserted
                //override EditorUi.saveFile function for customization
                this.save = saveXml;
                function saveXml() {

                    if (editorUI.editor.graph.isEditing()) {
                        editorUI.editor.graph.stopEditing();
                    }

                    var xml = mxUtils.getXml(editorUI.editor.getGraphXml());
                    //xml = encodeURIComponent(xml);

                    if (xml.length < MAX_REQUEST_SIZE) {
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "home/save",
                            processData: false,
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            data: JSON.stringify({ 'xml': xml }),
                            success: function (response) {
                                //alert(response.message);
                            },
                            error: function (ex) {
                                alert(ex.message);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    else {
                        mxUtils.alert(mxResources.get('drawingTooLarge'));
                        mxUtils.popup(xml);

                        return;
                    }

                };

                //reset onload open function                               
                this.open = defaultOpen;
                function defaultOpen() {};

            };

        })();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried with your solution mentioned above, but its showing blank page. Can you share the whole code here?

Comment: you shall watch your browser's console occurred bugs and replace **js** files in folders to solve bugs. Tell me your result I will help you to get result.